# Does asymptotic normally imply uniform integrability?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, uniform-integrability

If a set of random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is asymptotically normal is it also uniformly integrable?

Intuitively it seems like this should be true as $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ becomes 'nicer' as $n$ gets larger with the density becoming more symmetrical about the mean.

So is it true? If not, are there additional conditions we can impose on the set of asymptotically normal random variables to make them uniformly integrable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable, and $B_n$'s are i.i.d. Bernoulli$(\frac{n-1}{n})$ independent of $Z$, then define
$$X_n = ZB_n +n^2 (1-B_n).$$

Note that
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n\leq x) = \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\mathbb{P}(Z\leq x) + \frac{1}{n}\mathbb{P}(n^2 \leq x),
$$

The last probability is either $0$ or $1$, thus $X_n$ converges to standard normal as $n \to \infty$. Moreover $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|) = n$. Now from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2541010/885456), conclude $X_n$'s are not UI. Also the link gives you necessery and sufficient conditions for UI.

Comment: Very interesting thanks. I can see now that it doesn't hold in general, however maybe it holds for the specific family of R.V.s I am interested in. I am interested in the standard ordinary least squares regression coefficients $\hat{\beta}_n = \beta + (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \varepsilon$ where I used the subscript $n$ to indicate the number of observations. Is $\{\hat{\beta}_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ uniformly integrable?

Comment: Actually, I will ask it as a separate question as you have correctly answered the original question so I should mark that as solved.

Comment: The follow-up question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062656/are-the-ordinary-least-squares-coefficients-uniformly-integrable)