# Are the ordinary least squares regression coefficients uniformly integrable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables, regression, uniform-integrability

In my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062560/does-asymptotic-normally-imply-uniform-integrability) I asked whether a set of asymptotically normal random variables $\{X_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ are uniformly integrable. In the accepted answer the poster showed that this does not hold in general.

Now what about a specific case. Consider the standard ordinary least squares (OLS) regression coefficients $\hat{\beta}_n = \beta + (X_n^T X_n)^{-1} X_n^T \varepsilon$ where I have used the subscript $n$ to indicate that these are the OLS coefficients for a regression model with $n$ observations. Is $\{\hat{\beta}_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ uniformly integrable? Of course, $\hat{\beta}_n$ is a random vector, so I am asking whether the elements of this vector, which are all asymptotically normal, are uniformly integrable.

Note that the $X_n$ above are stochastic regressors, not fixed.

**Edit: Attempt for the case of single regressor with no intercept**
Here is an attempt for the case of a single regressor with no intercept, i.e., the regression model is
$$
Y = X \beta + \varepsilon,
$$
where we have $n$ i.i.d observations $Y = [Y_1,Y_2,\dots,Y_n]^T$ and regressors $X = [X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n]^T$, and $\varepsilon = [\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2,\dots,\varepsilon_n]^T$. The errors are mutually independent with $E[\varepsilon_i|X] = 0$ and they all have the same finite variance $\sigma^2$.

Let $\hat \beta_n$ denote the OLS estimate for $\beta$ where the subscript $n$ indicates the number of observations in the regression model.

Note that because we only have a single regressor that $(X^T X)^{-1}$ reduces from a matix to a scalar:
$$
(X^T X)^{-1} = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i^2\bigg)^{-1}. 
$$

From what I understand, to show that $\{\hat \beta_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly integrable, it is enough to show that there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\sup_n E[|\hat\beta_n|^{1 + \delta}] < \infty$.

First, I think that wlog we can consider $\hat\beta_n - \beta$ instead of $\hat\beta_n$ in the above expectation. Let's take $\delta = 1$ and define $A = (X^TX)^{-1}$. Then

\begin{align}
E[|\hat\beta_n - \beta|^2]
&= 
E[|A\varepsilon|^2] \\
&= 
E[A\varepsilon \varepsilon A^T] \\
&= 
E[A E[\varepsilon \varepsilon|X]A^T] \\
&= 
\sigma^2 E[AA^T] \\
&= 
\sigma^2 E[(X^TX)^{-1}].
\end{align}

It is commonly assumed that $\text{plim}_{n\to \infty} (X^TX/n) \stackrel{p}{\to} Q$ where $Q$ is a positive constant (usually a positive definite matrix, but since we only have a single regressor its a scalar in our case). And thus $$
\text{plim}_{n\to \infty} (X^TX/n)^{-1} \stackrel{p}{\to} Q^{-1}.
$$

Write $(X^TX)^{-1} = n^{-1}(X^TX/n)^{-1}$ and substitute into the expectation above to get
\begin{align}
E[|\hat\beta_n - \beta|^2] \
& = \sigma^2 E[(X^TX)^{-1}] \\
& = \sigma^2 n^{-1} E[(X^TX/n)^{-1}].
\end{align}
Now we know $(X^TX/n)^{-1} \stackrel{p}{\to} Q^{-1}$ and if can convert this convergence in probability into convergence in expectation we will have shown that $E[|\hat\beta_n - \beta|^2] < \infty$ (in fact it will go to zero due to the $n^{-1}$ coefficient), and thus the OLS regression coefficients are uniformly integrable.

So it seems the problem of uniform integrability of the OLS regression coefficients reduces to the uniform integrability of $(X^TX/n)^{-1}$.

**So here are my questions now:**

1. Does my analysis seem correct?
2. Is $(X^TX/n)^{-1}$ uniformly integrable?
3. If $(X^TX/n)^{-1}$ is not uniformly integrable by default is it reasonable to assume it is uniformly integrable? How strong an assumption would this be?

P.S. We have $(X^TX/n)^{-1} = \bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2\bigg)^{-1}$. So is the inverse of the second sample moment uniformly integrable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OLS regression coefficients are uniformly integrable. I refer you to this article that proves it along the way: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.02962.pdf

Comment: I believe that article is for OLS regression coefficients in which the regressors are fixed. I am interested in the regression model $Y = X \beta + \varepsilon$ where $X$ is stochastic not fixed.

Comment: In that paper they define $X$ as being an $n\times p$ matrix of real numbers.

Comment: Well, you are right, things may change now... ok, consider mine as only a partial result then...